# messy code in emacs vc-mode

Tags: git, emacs, elisp, emacs23

commit source code into git repository with emacs vc-mode.
I used Chinese characters to write commit message. and push the changeset into github
then all of the Chinese characters changed to be irrecognizable

[image]

**↓↓↓↓↓↓After push into github↓↓↓↓↓↓↓**

[image]

Comment: good idea is to start using english

Comment: What about the steps in between? Is the text already garbled in the local repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC does not know what particular backends use for character encodings (yes, that's a bug in VC for those backends which do specify that the encoding has to be utf-8), so it probably encoded your comment using your locale's favorite encoding (say big5) insead of using github's expected utf-8 (or so I guess).